# Is fear not as bad as anger and lust?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

In **Geetha** it is said that **lust and anger are worse qualities**.

But it didn't stress any where that **fear is a bad quality**. Am I correct? Is there any slokha explicitly saying that fear is very worse quality?

If not, is fear not as bad as lust and angry?

Comment: Anger and desire are the two fundamental evils which combine to create other qualities that is why Kamokarshit japa is given to a sadhak to realize the fundamental evils.

Comment: I don't see the Gita saying that fear is one of the worst qualities. Fear is an upadhi, a natural occurance to all living beings. The greatest upadhis are lust and greed. Fear will drop off by itself when the heart is controlled, when lust and gold are controlled..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gita classifies fear as a bad quality as can be seen in this shloka:

> Freed from passion, **fear** and anger, ever absorbed in My thought,
>   and ever dependent on Me - many have attained to My state, being
>   purified by the fire of knowledge and austerity.

Gita 4.10

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure how fear compares with lust and anger or which one is worse; but fear is certainly not good as talked by Swami Vivekananda [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_7/Conversations_And_Dialogues/V)

> Fear is death, fear is sin, fear is hell, fear is unrighteousness, fear is wrong life. All the negative thoughts and ideas that are in this world have proceeded from this evil spirit of fear.

Quoting Sri Ramakrishna on fear [here](http://www.estudantedavedanta.net/gospel_srk.pdf) (search page 145)

> One should not be ashamed of chanting God's holy name.  As the 
>   saying   goes, 'One does not succeed so long as one has these three: shame, hatred, and fear.'

But the fear of God is necessary as it prevents one from acting in immoral and illegal ways.

Answer (score 0):

Our ancient scriptures never classified passion, fear, anger, etc, as bad qualities.  **They are only weaknesses .**  That is why it was said:

> आहार-निद्रा-भय-मैथुनं च समानमेतत्पशुभिर्नराणाम् ।
> धर्मो हि तेषामधिको विशेषो धर्मेण हीनाः पशुभिः समानाः ॥
>
> "food, sleep, fear and mating, these acts of humans are similar to animals'.  Of them (humans), dharma (right conduct) is the only special thing, without dharma humans are also animals."

(hitopadeshaH kathAmrutam  http://blog.practicalsanskrit.com/2010/01/human-or-animal-what-is-difference.html)

Through this sloka, we are told about **common traits** to both animals and human beings and about that quality DHARMA, which separates animals from Human beings.

Again, passion, fear, anger, etc, are not weaknesses in all cases .

We have to understand that passion, fear, anger, etc, **may be impediment for a person desiring to progress SPIRITUALLY,** but not to a student or a householder.

1. If a student does not have passion towards his studies, he can not gain knowledge.
2. If a parents do not show anger towards misbehaving children, they can not set them on right path
3. If a person does not learn to fear about hazardous materials like electricity, poisonous chemicals, explosives, etc (or) wild animals (or) dangerous situations, it will pose threat to very life of humans.  Are not animals running away out of fear, when a threat to their life has been perceived?

---

In respect of humans desiring to progress spiritually, passion, fear, anger, etc, these are to be considered weaknesses only but not bad qualities.

Unless the spiritual aspirant overcomes his weaknesses, i.e., passion, fear, anger, etc, his progress will be little.

The life of Sage Vishwamitra is an example in this regard.  As long as he was overwhelmed by his weaknesses like desire for opposite sex, anger, ego, jealousy,etc, he could not succeed in his attempts.

Comment: @DoubleDouble:It is always advisable to introduce yourself, before making any comments, when you are not familiar with the customs of other cultures.

Comment: Hello, I'm DoubleDouble. I disagree on "2." - anger is not necessary to set children on the right path. The only thing anger does is make you more violent. This is only helpful if you are in a violent situation. (*But, I am not familiar with Hinduism - is this something Hinduism teaches?*)

Comment: Can you please add to the answer, the reference for the shloka you used? (where it is from, link will help)

Comment: @DoubleDouble:  I could infer from your sarcastic comments that you do not belong to Hinduism and perhaps, you may not belong to this country.  I do not know how you people set the children in right path, without expressing your anger, slapping, if necessary, when they misbehave.  Even my father shouted at me and slapped rarely, when I was in my teens and misbehaved.  I learnt the lesson.

Comment: @sv.:  I used to hear this verse ever since I started showing interest in spiritualism, but I never cared for the source of this sloka.  I will try to get it.

Comment: You are probably correct that I am not from your country, and am not familiar with your teachings, but I am not being sarcastic. I am genuinely wondering where that point comes from so I can understand why my own beliefs differ.

Comment: If I seemed confrontational I apologize.

Comment: @sv.: I have come across the above sloka in a Blog, where the author stated this sloka was mentioned in hitopadesh kathAmukham.  http://blog.practicalsanskrit.com/2010/01/human-or-animal-what-is-difference.html .   I added the reference in my answer

Comment: The Hitopadesha isn't really Hindu scripture, so you should try to find a source in Hindu scripture for the notion that Dharma is what distinguishes humans from animals.

Comment: @DoubleDouble:  In our country, bringing a child in to this world is not the only duty of the parents.  It is the responsibility of the parents to see that their children do not misbehave, tread in wrong path, etc, till they reach adulthood.  It is a duty, and the parents are supposed to discharge.  Even after many attempts by the parents, if children do not fall in line, it is not the mistake of the parents, as they tried their best.  It is the fate of the children to become so.  I do not also claim that every parent is following this duty nowadays.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan:  Sure. I will try to get another authenticated source.

Comment: You can modify your 3rd statement stating that people should "fear" about hazardous materials. Fear is probably not the best word to use.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria: I could not get an alternative suitable word.  you can suggest a suitable word.  And, if that word found suitable, I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: In Ramayana, while replying to Vali, Sri Rama says that if a person deviates from Dharma, he should be punished. यवीयान् आत्मनः पुत्रः शिष्यः च अपि गुणोदितः |
पुत्रवत् ते त्रयः चिंत्या धर्मः चैव अत्र कारणम् || ४-१८-१४ "An younger brother, a son, and a disciple with good characteristics, these three are to be deemed as one's own sons, for such matters take base on rectitude alone.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: तद् व्यतीतस्य ते धर्मात् काम वृत्तस्य वानर |
भ्रातृ भार्या अभिमर्शे अस्मिन् दण्डो अयम् प्रतिपादितः || ४-१८-२०"Thereby, oh, vanara, this punishment is imposed on you, for your dissolute sinning in abusing your brother's wife, thereby for your transgression of tradition and virtue.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Hinduism does not teach anger and violence. Anger is an upadhi as is fear. They both only bind a soul more to the world and to rebirth.